# Placeholder for time input in Safari

Tags: html, css, forms, cross-browser, html-input

I am using `<input type="time" />`. Chrome, Firefox, and Edge renders it properly i.e. the placeholder used is : `--:-- --` where as Safari uses `12:30 PM` as a placeholder. What is the workaround for this problem?

I tried CSS solution but same issue occurs.

Comment: Which version of Safari are you using?
What's the `value` of the input?